# jquery hide div tag that have appended table inside of it

Tags: jquery, hide, show

For example

```
<div id="hideThis">
 <button>trigger</button>
 <div>some content</div
 <table>
  some code...
 </table>
</div> 
<div id="showThis" class="hidden">
</div>
```

How can I hide the entire hideThis div. because when i try to hide it, the appended table remains.
i used the .html() for the table.

i was trying to hideThis div and show another div which is hidden using a button..

```
   $('button').click(function() {
        $("#hideThis").toggleClass('hidden');
        $("#showThis").toggleClass('hidden');
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net with the problem?

Comment: i wrongly generate the table. the table were generated in hideThis and showThis div. so that's why the table is not hiding.thank you guys for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine.  You just were missing a closing angle bracket `>` to close the `some content` DIV.

Here is a jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ym1vrsg0/

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $("#hideThis").toggleClass('hidden');
    $("#showThis").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Ha, that was a nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery had a shortcut method for hiding and displaying HTML elements.

```
$('button').click(function() {
     $("#hideThis").hide();
     $("#showThis").hide();
 });
```

Comment: `.hidden` is a popular class that people use instead of `.hide()`.

Comment: In jQuery?  Thought OP wanted jQuery solution and for the . hidden class to work it would require a review of the styling which wasn't posted... Or does jQuery include a CSS fine I've been oblivious to?!

Comment: Try setting the containing DIV CSS display property to inline-block.

Comment: Yeah, `.hidden` is popular, especially in Bootstrap. You can then do something like `addClass('hidden')` to hide elements.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

$('#hideThis').hide();

$('#showThis').show();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function() {
 $("#hideThis").hide();
 $("#showThis").show();
});
```

this will hide the hidethis class and show showthis class

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0dr3pfy6/2/

Comment: i want to hide the first and show the second, but the appended table can't be hide. even though it is inside the hideThis div.